# ASP.NET Core EF: how to use EF without any migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on ASP.NET Core project.
Is it possible to use ASP.NET Core Identity with EF but without any migrations?
I.e. I can create the ASP.NET structure manually and use it via EF.
But I do not want to have any problems with migrations because ASP.NET Core Identity Db srtucture is stable.
Any examples how to?

Comment: Do you mean database first? Is so, yes, you can do that

Comment: Ok, how to do that? To avoid errors like table AspNet.Users does not exists etc

Comment: You can. You can do `update-database ...` with an optional flag `-script` to generate scripts instead of creating those tables (and the migration history table) in the database. Run scripts to generate structure manually. And then go back to your project and delete the migration folder.

Comment: @DavidLiang thanx. Shoudl I do anything in DBConext.cs code too?

Comment: @Oleg: if you need to rename those tables, you can, but other than that, as long as the database table structures match those entity classes and you do manually update the structures when there is a change, you don't need to do anything in the db context.